# Where to ask for hardware advice? (netbook)

Tags: support

What is the right site to ask about hardware advice? In particular, I realize serverfault would be right for big iron, but what about netbooks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If by 'hardware advice' you mean $product recommendations then there probably isn't anywhere as [shopping questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) are generally off topic.

If you are after general troubleshooting advice etc then for netbooks Superuser is probably your best bet.

Comment: Caveat: If you're asking about troubleshooting advice for a Mac product you may want to try [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 3):

There's worse ideas than asking on serverfault chat, we're fully of options and ideas on there.

Comment: Jeff Atwood himself set up a chat room for product recommendations of routers so this seems a likely place